# how to link a Python C module

Tags: python, linux, ld

I have written a Python C module (just `ffmpeg.c` which depends on some FFmpeg libs and other libs) and I am wondering how to link.

I'm compiling with:

`cc -std=c99 -c ../ffmpeg.c -I /usr/include/python2.7 -g`

I'm trying to link right now with:

`ld -shared -o ../ffmpeg.so -L/usr/local/lib -lpython2.7 -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lswresample -lportaudio -lchromaprint ffmpeg.o -lc`

There is no error. However, when I try to `import ffmpeg` in Python, I get:

`ImportError: ./ffmpeg.so: undefined symbol: avio_alloc_context`

---

Maybe this is already correct. I checked the resulting `ffmpeg.so` with `ldd` and it partly links to a wrong FFmpeg. This is strange however because of the `-L/usr/local/lib` which should take precedence over the default. Maybe because my custom installed FFmpeg (in `/usr/local/lib`) has for some reason only installed static `*.a` libs and `*.so` files have precedence over `*.a` files.

Comment: Are you sure your ffmpeg.c is implemented in the correct way to produce a Python library?

Comment: @hamon: I guess so. I already was able to build the module on MacOSX (via `libtool`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the libraries that you're linking to **after** the `.o` file; i.e.:

```
ld -shared -o ../ffmpeg.so ffmpeg.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpython2.7 -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lswresample -lportaudio -lchromaprint -lc
```

The linker is dumb, and will not link in code from static libraries that it doesn't think are needed until a dependency arises i.e. the use of `avio_alloc_context` happens in `ffmpeg.o`, and because it's not listed after the use of the library, then the linker will not consider the code in the library as needed, so it doesn't get linked in - this is the biggest reason why linking using `.a` files fails.

You can also use `--start-group` and `--end-group` around all the files that you are linking - this allows you to link static libraries that have cross dependencies that just seem impossible to resolve through other means:

```
ld -shared -o ../ffmpeg.so -L/usr/local/lib -lpython2.7 --start-group -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lswresample -lportaudio -lchromaprint ffmpeg.o --end-group -lc
```

using `.a` files is a little bit trickier than `.so` files, but these two items generally will work around any issues you have when linking.

Comment: There aren't any shared libs of FFmpeg in my case, so this shouldn't make a difference? `sudo ldconfig` did not change anything.

Comment: Please see the updated answer - put the `ffmpeg.o` *before* all the -l options and it should link correctly

Comment: I already did it in that order. That was not the problem. I figured it out now. Chromaprint still linked to another FFmpeg lib version and that was the problem. I just removed it and installed it manually. Another `sudo ldconfig` was also needed. It worked then. My `ld` command is actually correct and works.